# Query string with AND operator in nested query not working. Any idea?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I want to get the document in which nested child contains both words **Mifune** AND **Miller-Meteor**.

For more detail of nested, I've gone through https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html

here are the mappings

```
{
    "mappings" : {
        "properties" : {
            "driver" : {
                "type" : "nested",
                "properties" : {
                    "last_name" : {
                        "type" : "text"
                    },
                    "vehicle" : {
                        "type" : "nested",
                        "properties" : {
                            "make" : {
                                "type" : "text"
                            },
                            "model" : {
                                "type" : "text"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i've two documents in the index

```
{
  "driver" : {
        "last_name" : "McQueen",
        "vehicle" : [
            {
                "make" : "Powell Motors",
                "model" : "Canyonero"
            },
            {
                "make" : "Miller-Meteor",
                "model" : "Ecto-1"
            }
        ]
    }
},{
  "driver" : {
        "last_name" : "Hudson",
        "vehicle" : [
            {
                "make" : "Mifune",
                "model" : "Mach Five"
            },
            {
                "make" : "Miller-Meteor",
                "model" : "Ecto-1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

query as below

```
{
    "query" : {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "driver",
            "query" : {
                "nested" : {
                    "path" :  "driver.vehicle",
                    "query" :  {
                        "bool" : {
                            "must" : [
                                { "match" : { "driver.vehicle.make" : "Mifune" } },
                                { "match" : { "driver.vehicle.make" : "Miller-Meteor" } }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the above query but it did not work
also tried with query_string AND operator but it also not worked

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "driver",
            "query": {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "driver.vehicle",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "query_string": {
                                        "query": "Mifune AND Miller-Meteor",
                                        "fields": ["driver.vehicle.make"]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try terms maybe: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/query-dsl-terms-query.html

Comment: Thanks. trying that.

Comment: Terms query also not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should query multiple nested fields.

There are two `Nested` queries inside your must clause.

The `bool->must` operator should be outside of your internal nested fields.

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "driver",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "driver.vehicle",
                "query": {
                  "match": {
                    "driver.vehicle.make": "Mifune"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "driver.vehicle",
                "query": {
                  "match": {
                    "driver.vehicle.make": "Miller-Meteor"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
"timed_out" : false,
 "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 2.769686,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 2.769686,
        "_source" : {
          "driver" : {
            "last_name" : "Hudson",
            "vehicle" : [
              {
                "make" : "Mifune",
                "model" : "Mach Five"
              },
              {
                "make" : "Miller-Meteor",
                "model" : "Ecto-1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[Nested DataType](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the give solution but it is not working.

Comment: I tried it and it worked. what do you get when you run it? see Results in my answer

Comment: let me check is there anything wrong with my query.

Comment: Base on the mappings and indexed documents you provide just copy paste my query and change **my_index** to your actual index.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. there's a little mistake in my query.

Comment: can i use terms query within single must object for all words ?

Comment: terms means OR between your values. and you will have to change your mapping. in order to use terms you will have to add a keyword type to your fields

Comment: I've added keyword to the field make and tried with terms query not working. It is giving me all two documents instead of second one which is expected result.

Comment: is there any other efficient way for this? because in the case for more than two words i can not add match blocks for all the given words? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As i told you. terms means OR so you will get both documents and btw my answer solved your issue with **AND Operator** and the **ACCEPT** shouldn't have been removed.

Comment: Sorry for that. it was by mistakenly removed. i'm new to here after a long time so.
You are right but i've to search for multiple words for all the words i've to add blocks.
Let me know the better option if you have.

Comment: No problem. i'll see what i can do. but the best option is to use **must**